# PHP Loop determine 4th iteration but if the iteration is less than 4 echo something

Tags: php, html, css

Heres the scenario, I have array with 7 items and I want to separate them in every fourth iteration.. just like this

```
    $counter2 = 0;
    $counter3 = 0;
    $counter4 = 0;
    $sample_array = array('Aso','Pusa','Daga','Kuting','Tuta','Bubwit','Boom');
    foreach($sample_array as $sample_array_value)
    {
        if(++$counter4 % 4 == 0)
        {
            echo $sample_array_value;
            echo "</div>";
        }
        elseif(++$counter3 % 3 == 0)
        {
            echo $sample_array_value;
        }
        elseif(++$counter2 % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo $sample_array_value;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div>";
            echo $sample_array_value;
        }
    }
```

The out put will be div AsoPusaDagaKuting /div div TutaBubwitBoom

The problem is when it ends in iteration that doesn't count 4 it doesn't give the separator ending..

I need it to output  div AsoPusaDagaKuting /div div TutaBubwitBoom /div

Thanks in advance...

Comment: all 7 are echoed then why that much stuff?

Comment: Whatever is `%4=0` is also `%2=0`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky but something can be %2=0 but not %4=0, so it still makes sense (even if it doesn't do what he want...)

Comment: Also your code works as you want separate after each 4 element. then what's the problem?

Comment: @Random You are right. But  Hanky 웃 Panky is saying *Whatever is %4=0 is also %2=0* and this is true. `only %4=0 then %2=0` & `only %2=0 then %4=0` is different

Comment: @anant the problem is when the last iteration is not count to 4 it doesn't give the ending..

Comment: @b0s3 but that case never happen since it is in an `else`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($sample_array as $sample_array_value)
{
    if(++$counter4 % 4 == 0)
    {
        echo $sample_array_value;
        echo "</div>";
    }
    elseif(++$counter3 % 3 == 0 || ++$counter2 % 2 == 0)
    {
        echo $sample_array_value;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div>";
        echo $sample_array_value;
    }

    $i++;
}

if ($i % 4 != 0) {
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split it with array_chunk, implode the new subarrays of 4 with array_map, then echo it with implode.

```
$sample_array = array('Aso','Pusa','Daga','Kuting','Tuta','Bubwit','Boom');
echo "<div>", implode("</div><div>", array_map("implode", array_chunk($sample_array, 4))), "</div>";
```

Result:

```
<div>AsoPusaDagaKuting</div><div>TutaBubwitBoom</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing the values inside every condition, then why not use `echo` once outside any condition? Also you want to close and open a `div` tag for the forth element, then only 1 counter would do the trick. Only this will work -

```
$sample_array = array('Aso','Pusa','Daga','Kuting','Tuta','Bubwit','Boom');
$i = 0;
echo "<div>";
foreach($sample_array as $sample_array_value)
{
    if($i > 0 && $i % 4 == 0)
    {
        echo "</div><div>";
    }
    echo $sample_array_value;
    $i++;
}
echo "</div>";
```

**Output**

```
<div>AsoPusaDagaKuting</div><div>TutaBubwitBoom</div>
```